# Android Context Menu

Tags: android, contextmenu

I want to create a Context Menu. I tried the following

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}

public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.menuex, menu);
}
```

Why is my Context Menu not showing up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `registerForContextMenu(View)` to register a context menu for a specific item.

Comment: can i register the menu for any number of items ?

Comment: Sure, there are no restrictions.